# avconv Unknown encoder 'libx264' i try all solution but not working

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I have this problem with avconv:

```
Unknown encoder 'libx264'
```

For adding subtitle I use:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:v libx264 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 1 -b:v 512k -strict -2 -c:a aac -ac 2 -filter:v subtitles=1.srt Video_With-Subtitle.mp4
```

Can you give me solution, and what is best solution for burn subtitle fast on Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

## Use ffmpeg

`avconv` is not the same as `ffmpeg`, and `avconv` does not have the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles).

Solutions:

- 16.04 and 18.04 have `ffmpeg` in the repo. Install with `sudo apt install ffmpeg`, or
- [Download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and put it in `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`, or
- Follow [FFmpeg Wiki: How to Compile and Install ffmpeg on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Then run:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -filter:v subtitles=1.srt -c:a copy output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) to see how to control quality (`-crf`) and encoding speed (`-preset`).

Comment: Thx Sir but ffmeg is real slow not fast

Comment: @SnipersTV Using filters requires encoding. Encoding is slow. Use a faster `-preset`. Example: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -filter:v subtitles=1.srt -c:a copy output.mp4`

Comment: Thx sir for your reponse                                                                                                                can you burn subtitle with MP4Box because is very fast ?

Comment: @SnipersTV I am not familiar enough with MP4Box/gpac to be able to answer that, and I didn't search.